# Change height of image in html using jQuery on pageload

Tags: jquery, html

I have the main content in a div in the middle of the page, with two pictures either side, acting as shadows.  The page length can vary so I want the shadow length to vary with it.

Here is the HTML set up:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="shadow_container">
    <img src="catalog/view/theme/furniture/image/left-shadow.png" height="400px" width="61px" id="left_shadow"/>
        <div class="main_container">

            pagecontentpagecontentpagecontent

        </div>
    <img src="catalog/view/theme/furniture/image/right-shadow.png" height="400px" width="61px" id="right_shadow"/>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(".shadow_container").load(function(){
    var shadowHeight = $(".shadow_container").height();
    var newShadowHeight = shadowHeight+85+" px";

    $("#left_shadow").height(newShadowHeight);
    $("#right_shadow").height(newShadowHeight);
});
```

Where am I going wrong!?

Okay, just to clarify, I have tested it using absolute values in the last 2 lines and nothing happens.

All the other jQuery in the external script works, and this section is just after my document ready, so why isn't this running?

Comment: ``var newShadowHeight = shadowHeight+85;``

and:
``$("#left_shadow").height(newShadowHeight);``

Comment: if height was css, you should use +'px', but in your example it is attr so you can't use 'px' at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the px `var newShadowHeight = shadowHeight+85+" px";` should be:
`var newShadowHeight = shadowHeight+85;`

And you can use the shorthand for setting height, the same way you use it to retrieve it:

```
$("#left_shadow").height(newShadowHeight);
$("#right_shadow").height(newShadowHeight);
```

So rewritten to automatically change the shadow on body load:

```
$(function(){
    var shadowHeight = $(".shadow_container").height();
    var newShadowHeight = shadowHeight+85;

    $("#left_shadow").height(newShadowHeight);
    $("#right_shadow").height(newShadowHeight);
});
```

Comment: what is your debug console saying?

Answer (score 0):

Try without "px". Just numbers.